# how to get selected radiobutton from radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have one radiobuttonlist which consists of two radio button,following price discount,another is percent discount. the code snippet of aspx file as follows:

```
<td class="style8">
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Price Discount</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Percent Discount</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue
```

return an integer number (1 or 2) which you have declared  in your aspx code 
if select price discount then returns 1 of select percent then return 2 .

```
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Price Discount</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="2">Percent Discount</asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two way.

```
1. If you want to select radio button by your value then you can write


    RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue 

2.If you want to select radio button by your Item then you can write

RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get RadioButtonList SelectedIndex,SelectedItem and SelectedValue

SelectedIndex:Gets or sets the lowest ordinal index of the selected items in the list.

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex
```

SelectedItem:Gets the selected item with the lowest index in the list control.

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem
```

SelectedValue:Gets the value of the selected item in the list control, or selects the item in the list control that contains the specified value.

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx